# Google Maps API - Error Geocoder Timeout Exception

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo un método el cual se encarga de devolverme una URL con latitud y longitud de acuerdo al término de búsqueda, el método es el siguiente:

```
public String getUrlFromTermsSearch(String searchTerm, Context context,String baseUrl){
    String url = "";

    try {
        Geocoder selected_place_geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> address;
        address = selected_place_geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchTerm,1);

        if (address.size()>0) {
            Address location = address.get(0);
            String urlF = baseUrl+searchTerm+"/"+location.getLatitude()+"/"+location.getLongitude()+"";
            url = urlF.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        }else{
            Log.d("error con Geocoder", ">>>: ");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Pero en algunos momentos muestra o devuelve una excepción en esta parte:

```
selected_place_geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchTerm,1);
```

La cual es

> error geocoder timeout exception

¿Cómo podría solucionar esta situación?.

Answer (score 0):

Este error me ha sucedido porque en ese momento no logra realizar la conexión con el servidor, ya sea porque estoy en una red movil y no tengo suficiente señal o simplemente mi internet esta fallando.

¿Que te recomiendo?

1) Colocar todo este método en una [Asynk Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

2) Verifica antes que en el momento de realizar la petición tienes internet activo.

**Otra solución:**

En vez de usar el geocoder, puedes hacer una solicitud al siguiente link:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=latitud,longitud&sensor=true
```

Éste te devolverá un JSON con las direcciones cercanas sustituyendo latitud y longitud por las coordenadas que necesitas. Por ejemplo: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.416786,-3.703680&sensor=true

Para más información de como personalizar la petición, puedes ingresar [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=es-419).